# Input::except behaves differently depending on my environment

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a problem with that function. I use `Input::except` to fetch a form that contains a sub form in an array.
For example here are the fields name in my form :

```
name, adress, zip, ville, card[number], card[deliveryDate]
```

here is my code  :

```
// This should give me an array with name adress zip and ville
$input = Input::except('card');
// This should give me an array with number and deliveryDate
$inputCard = Input::get('card');
```

This works fine in development. But when i deploy on staging server it fails.
`Input::except()` returns all the fields, like a `Input::all()`;

my development environment :

- Ubuntu 14.04 on a vagrant machine.
- PHP 5.5.19-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
- nginx 1.6.2

my staging environment :

- Ubuntu 14.04
- PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4
- nginx 1.4.6

I don't know where to look, particularly. So far all my environments behaved exactly the same.
If someone has an idea he's welcome.

ps : here is the `var_dump(Input::all());`, the output is exactly the same in both environment.

```
array (size=15)
'_method' => string 'PATCH' (length=5)
'nom' => string 'Some Company' (length=25)
'adresse' => string 'some adress' (length=22)
'complement_adresse' => string '' (length=0)
'cpville' => string 'someCity - 40000' (length=17)
'insee' => string '49999' (length=5)
'telephone' => string '+33(0)12312312' (length=15)
'email' => string 'someemail@gmail.com' (length=25)
'siteweb' => string 'www.website.fr' (length=31)
'fournisseur_id' => string '18' (length=2)
'carteTransac' => 
    array (size=4)
    'numero' => string '54512' (length=5)
    'departement_id' => string '312' (length=3)
    'image_recto' => null
    'image_verso' => null
'_url' => string '/agences/162' (length=12)
'photo' => null
```

The exact command that i did was `Input::except('carteTransac');`

Comment: Can you post a `var_dump` of `Input::all()`? (If there happens to be a difference between the dump on development and staging, post both)

Comment: i posted the var_dump you asked

Comment: How about `Input::except('carteTransac[]')`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i'm going to give it a try.

Comment: same wrong result on my staging server.

Comment: Hmm. Does it work correctly with a non-array input value? `Input::except('email')`

Comment: using a non array input value it works correctly on my development environment and it doesn't work on staging.

Comment: Strange. Can you try this (`except` does nothing else): `$all = Input::all(); array_forget($all, 'email'); var_dump($all);` and see if `email` is still in there?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's too old and based on deprecated versions of frameworks and languages.